# XSL compare elements in difference nodes and add the value of element in out put

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get a total of on hand items from two facility. I have tried several variations using `xsl:template match=""` and `xsl:for-each select=""` and have no luck and probable confused myself more at this point.

XML Structure:

```
    <Facility>
      <Id>92</Id>
      <Item>
        <Sku>10100200-99</Sku>
        <OnHand>623</OnHand>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Sku>10201400-00</Sku>
        <OnHand>509</OnHand>
      </Item>
    <Facility>
      <Id>99</Id>
      <Item>
        <Sku>10100100-99</Sku>
        <OnHand>0</OnHand>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Sku>10100200-99</Sku>
        <OnHand>725</OnHand>
      </Item>
```

Output wanted:

```
      <Item>
        <Sku>10100200-99</Sku>
        <OnHand>1348</OnHand>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Sku>10201400-00</Sku>
        <OnHand>509</OnHand>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Sku>10100100-99</Sku>
        <OnHand>0</OnHand>
      </Item>
```

On the output I would get all `<Sku>` with `<OnHand>` from `<Facility[1]>` and `<Facility[2]>` but if the `<Sku>` is in both then add the `<OnHand>` for a total. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a *grouping* question - do a search. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I would think you also need to post some valid XML. Your fragment is not valid. Is the Facility a child of Facility or? ...It is in your sample.

Comment: @Brad What's your XML file's root element? If we don't know your precise XML structure we cannot provide optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- define a set of Items identified by Sku -->
    <xsl:key name="groups" match="Item" use="Sku" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <!-- select always only the first Item with the same Sku -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', Sku)[1])]"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <Item>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Sku"/>
            <OnHand>
                <!-- sum OnHand of all Items with the same Sku -->
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('groups', Sku)/OnHand)"/>
            </OnHand>
        </Item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Starting a *match* pattern with a `//` is redundant. Starting a *select* expression with a `//` is bad practice.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You are right, I have fixed the *match* pattern. On the other hand, what's wrong with the `select="//..."` in this specific case? We have to find Items at any level. Please consider that the XML example is incomplete so we cannot name the parent elements explicitly here.

Comment: If the structure is truly unknown, you should at least use `.//` instead of `//`. It might not matter in this specific case, but selecting items from anywhere in the document can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @MathiasMüller In fact, I was not sure whether it matters here. I have changed it anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Using `//` or `.//` is permissible when the exact structure of the input XML is unknown at the time of writing the XSLT. I don't think that's the case here. The exact structure may be *unclear* due to OP's failure to produce a well-formed example of it, but that doesn't mean it's *unknown*.  I would have simply assumed a `Root -< Facility -< Item` structure and stated the assumption in my answer, instead of letting OP's less-than-ideal question translate to a less-than-ideal answer.